# Passing PHP variables to onLoad (JS)

Tags: php, javascript, onload

I am trying to pass two PHP variables to my onload tag. I keep getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"

The code I am using is:

```
<body onload="loadCalendar(<?php echo $profiletype; ?>,<?php echo $uid; ?>)">
```

The result of that code is:

```
<body onload="loadCalendar(a,29)">
```

which, to me looks fine - but I keep getting that error. Any thoughts?

Comment: you have a rogue variable `a` somewhere. it may not be in your body onload. maybe check things out with firebug?

Comment: Try `"<?php echo $profiletype; ?>"` to produce `"a"`.

Comment: I use google chromes debugging stuff - thats where I got the error from. I've done stuff like this before with onclicks in the exact same way and its worked fine, hence my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it this instead.

```
<body onload="loadCalendar('<?php echo $profiletype; ?>',<?php echo $uid; ?>)">
```

When you don't have that value quoted, it interprets `a` as a variable and not a string.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to accept answers if they've solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing some single quotes

```
<body onload="loadCalendar('<?php echo $profiletype; ?>','<?php echo $uid; ?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the returned `$profiletype`:

```
<body onload="loadCalendar('<?php echo $profiletype; ?>',<?php echo $uid; ?>)">
```

If you don't then the value will be taken literally -- in the case of `a` a variable by that name, hence the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`.